# How to insert multiple rows using a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.3

I want to insert more than one row in a table with function in PostgreSQL.

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE mahasiswa
(
  nim CHAR(10),
  nama VACHAR(40)
  CONSTRAINT pk_nim PRIMARY KEY (nim)
)
;
```

and this is the function I created

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertdata(CHAR(10),varchar(40)) 
       RETURNS VOID AS 
       $$ 
         INSERT INTO mahasiswa VALUES ($1,$2); 
       $$ 
       LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

When I call the function like this

```
SELECT insertdata ('1234567890','Nahrun'),
('0987654321','Hartono');
```

only one row is inserted.

How can I modify my function to insert more than one row at a time?

Comment: That's not possible. First because your function only has two parameters and secondly because your `INSERT` statement is written in such a way that it only inserts a single row.

Comment: Can you give me an example to insert multiple rows using a function in PostgreSQL

Comment: Give me some examples,
please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **function you have** should rather be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertdata(varchar(10),varchar(40)) 
  RETURNS VOID AS 
$$ 
   INSERT INTO mahasiswa(col_name1, col_name2)
   VALUES ($1,$2); 
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

- Don't quote the language name. It's an identifier.
- Always provide a target list with persisted statements. Else, if you later change the table definition, the function can behave in unexpected ways.
- Never use `char(n)`, unless you know what you are doing. I'd just use `text`.

To **insert multiple rows**, you can take an array of composite type or two arrays with the *same number of elements* to unnest in parallel. Demonstrating the latter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertdata(_arr1 text[], _arr2 text[]) 
  RETURNS VOID AS 
$$ 
   INSERT INTO mahasiswa(col_name1, col_name2)
   SELECT unnest(_arr1), unnest(_arr2);
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

Call:

```
SELECT insertdata ('{1234567890,0987654321}', '{Nahrun,Hartono}');
```

I would rather use a plpgsql function and check that the number of elements is the same in both arrays to prevent mistakes. Use `array_length(arr1, 1)` ...

#### Postgres 9.4 or later ...

... introduced a new variant of unnest that accepts multiple arrays in parallel - without the quirks of the above hack (never defaults to a `CROSS JOIN`)

```
   INSERT INTO mahasiswa(col_name1, col_name2)
   SELECT * FROM unnest(_arr1, _arr2);  -- must be in FROM list
```

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/passing-arrays-to-stored-procedures-in-postgres/27854382#27854382)

Comment: Note: In the last PG 9.4 INSERT example when used with multiple arrays, a `SELECT * FROM unnest(...` is required or pg complains with an unmatched function error.

Comment: @hooblei: Thanks, fixed. The explanation is in the appended link, I still had the syntax error.